# type name is not allowed in C

Tags: c, casting, embedded, dma

I'm trying to use ADC with DMA using STM32F407. I want to set memory adress of `ADCValue` to  DMA stream x memory 0 address register. But i get this error:

```
type name is not allowed
```

This part is in `main`

```
unsigned short ADCValue[1];
DMA2_Stream0->M0AR= uint32_t(&ADCValue);
```

and definition of register

```
  __IO uint32_t M0AR;   /*!< DMA stream x memory 0 address register   */
```

Comment: `uint32_t(&ADCValue)` - what is it? If you want to cast, then the syntax would be `(uint32_t)&ADCValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting the wrong way. It should be:

```
DMA2_Stream0->M0AR = (uint32_t)&ADCValue;
```

But since it is an array, the `&` is not necessary either. An array will automatically decay to a pointer when used this way. So this will do:

```
DMA2_Stream0->M0AR = (uint32_t)ADCValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
unsigned short ADCValue ;
DMA2_Stream0->M0AR= (uint32_t)&ADCValue ;
```

or

```
unsigned short ADCValue[1] ;
DMA2_Stream0->M0AR= (uint32_t)ADCValue ;
```

`uint32_t(&ADCValue)` or `uint32_t(ADCValue)` is valid in C++ but not C.